# Make two or more commands be able to run at the same time in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

On my Discord bot I have a command that will search Google for whatever the user put in. But if this command is run at the same time in two or more different places, then the first search has to load before the second one will start. How can I have both run at the same time?
Here is the code for the search:

```
@bot.command("search")
async def search(ctx, *, arg=""):
    if arg == "":
        await ctx.send(embed=error(title="No Query", desc="You need to put in what you want to search"))
    else:
        
        loading = await ctx.send(embed=msg(thumbnail="https://media4.giphy.com/media/dOmQEMUbT2fWKy7hCA/giphy.gif"))
        results = []
        for j in googlesearch.search(arg, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=10, pause=2.0, safe="on"):
            results.append(j)
        answer = ""
        for i in range(0, len(results)):
            answer += results[i] + "\n"
        await loading.delete()
        if answer.replace(" ", "") == "":
            answer = "No Results (aww man)"
        await ctx.send(embed=msg(title="Search results", desc=answer + "\n Most relevant results at the top."))
```

And the import is `import googlesearch`.
msg() returns an embed.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I would suggest showing your code as well.

Comment: Post your code. Also, make the command have a cooldown so it gives time for the first search to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `googlesearch` uses `requests` which blocks the whole code

Read More about "What Blocking Means": [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)

Solution:

**Either use `aiohttp` to directly do async HTTP requests to Google or find a module that uses async HTTP requests that satisfies your need**